# HeaderText Datagridgridview Alignment

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

[image: Header]

I have many Headers in the datagridview and the HeaderText is quite long for example 4 words. So the Datagridcell becomes big. I want to break the 4 words and put one by one below to reduce the size.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.headertext.aspx

I tried checking the above link but I couldn't succeed.

Comment: Perhaps the [DataGridViewColumn.HeaderCell Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.headercell) will help you. You could create a new Style and change the [DataGridViewCellStyle.WrapMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.wrapmode.aspx)

Comment: Check also my answer. I think it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataGridView.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = 
    DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;

foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView.Columns)
{
    column.HeaderCell.Style.WrapMode= DataGridViewTriState.True;
}
```

Comment: @red 3 mins ago

Schaliasos: WrapMoode, problem.

Comment: @linguini I think now it is ok

Comment: I have already tried the same from Microsoft website, it didn't work.

Comment: I just tried that and it worked. Maybe some other property prevents it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "VeryLong " + "LongLong" + Environment.NewLine + "LongLongLong";
```

`Environment.NewLine` made line break

[image: Result:]

Answer (score 0):

**First Option:** If you are looking for wrapping the text, the you can do that using CSS.
Apply the class to your datagrid header.

Allow long words to be able to break and wrap onto the next line:

```
.wrapText {word-wrap:break-word;}
```

or

```
.wrapText {word-wrap:normal;}
```

normal  - Break words only at allowed break points
break-word -    Allows unbreakable words to be broken

**Second Option:**
You can use datagrid "HeaderStyle" tag:

```
 <HeaderStyle Wrap="True"  />
```

Comment: It is a `Widows Form Application`